# TScrollPagerTool issue

Tags: delphi, teechart

I am trying the `TeeChart` software before I buy and was directed from their website to here for support. 
I am trying to get my head around using the `TScrollPagerTool` as it seems perfect for what I am trying to achieve but I am experiencing performance issues when resizing. 
In the resize event for the chart it is advised to add the following line if you are using this scrolling tool:

```
ScrollPagerTool.Series := Chart1.Series[0];
```

I don't know why you have to reassign the series but the chart won't resize without it. Further more that line effectively adds the Series again, meaning I have twice the series now and next resize, 3 times the series and so on, therefore I get a performance problem with scrolling after a few resizes.

Can someone tell me if I am doing this right or of an alternate method here?

I can post more code if required.

Answer (score 0):

First note that `TScrollPagerTool` uses a `TSubChartTool` with a clone of the main series in it. That's why the the SubChart is set when the `Series` is assigned, because it has no sense without a series.

In some TeeChart versions, the SubChart needs the main chart to be already drawn when you assign a series to the tool in order to calculate the space each chart should use (the `ChartRect`s). That's why we assign the series at the `OnResize` event, but I see in TeeChart VCL you can do it all at creation time:

```
uses Series, TeeScrollPagerTool;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin        
  Chart1.AddSeries(TLineSeries).FillSampleValues;
  (Chart1.Tools.Add(TScrollPagerTool) as TScrollPagerTool).Series:=Chart1[0];
end;
```

**BUG:**

I've seen there was actually a bug, as you said. Assigning the series in the `OnResize` event to make the chart and the subchart resize with the form, it made the source series to be cloned again and again:

```
uses Series, TeeScrollPagerTool;

var scrollPager1: TScrollPagerTool;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Chart1.Align:=alClient;

  scrollPager1:=Chart1.Tools.Add(TScrollPagerTool) as TScrollPagerTool;

  Chart1.AddSeries(TLineSeries).FillSampleValues;
  scrollPager1.Series:=Chart1[0];
end;

procedure TForm1.Chart1Resize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  scrollPager1.Series:=Chart1[0];
end;
```

I've made some changes to fix it:

In the next version, the `Series` property will remove all the series in the subchart and will clone the series assigned. So calling it several times won't end up in more and more clones. It will also call `SetUpScrollPager` that calculates the `ChartRect` for both the main chart and the subchart.

I've also made the `SetUpScrollPager` public so this will be the one to call at `OnResize` event to adjust the `ChartRect`s without needing to add or remove series.

```
procedure TForm1.Chart1Resize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  scrollPager1.SetUpScrollPager;
end;
```

**WORKAROUND:**

In the meanwhile, with the actual version you still could remove all the series in the SubChart and use the Series property to clone the source series, all at the `OnResize` event:

```
procedure TForm1.Chart1Resize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  scrollPager1.SubChartTChart.RemoveAllSeries;
  scrollPager1.Series:=Chart1[0];
end;
```

**RELATED FEATURE:**

How to have multiple series in the ScollPager? You can use the `SubChartTChart` property to access the subchart and add/remove any series to/from it. But you still need one series in the `Series` property. So it gets a bit tricky:

```
uses Series, TeeScrollPagerTool;

var scrollPager1: TScrollPagerTool;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var i: Integer;
begin
  Chart1.Align:=alClient;

  scrollPager1:=Chart1.Tools.Add(TScrollPagerTool) as TScrollPagerTool;

  for i:=0 to 4 do
  begin
    Chart1.AddSeries(TLineSeries).FillSampleValues;
    if scrollPager1.Series=nil then
      scrollPager1.Series:=Chart1[i]
    else
      scrollPager1.SubChartTChart.AddSeries(CloneChartSeries(Chart1[i]));
  end;
end;
```

That's why I've also added a new `AddSeries(const Value: TChartSeries)` method. Use it to add several series to the ScrollPager:

```
  for i:=0 to 4 do
  begin
    Chart1.AddSeries(TLineSeries).FillSampleValues;
    scrollPager1.AddSeries(Chart1[i]);
  end;
```

Comment: Whoops didn't finish my comment, the above answer is not quite there yet. If I use either of the code snippets above in the resize I lose the ability for the chart and the scroll pager to resize with the form which is not what I want. Can I use this code and still have the chart resize?

Comment: I just noticed something fairly important. I have 2 diff versions running on 2 machines. v2012.07.121105 32bit VCL using XE3 has the performance issues. v2013.08.130521 using delphi7, has no performance issues using exactly the same code. what the...?

Comment: Thanks for this Yeray, just to be clear am I still using: ScrollPagerTool.Series:=Chart1.Series[0] or SetUpScrollPager instead? Also do you mind pointing me in the direction of some good examples of implementing multiple function series in multiple subcharts? Cheers.

Comment: Having one series, you can still use ScrollPagerTool.Series:=Chart1.Series[0], but it will clear the series list and clone the Chart1.Series[0]. So doing it at the OnResize will do it again and again... Better calling SetUpScrollPager there. I've added a simple example in the answer.

Comment: Please, for different questions, create a new thread. Take a look at the demo at `All features\Welcome !\Axes\Opaque zones` in the new features demo.